# Using a MTLTexture as the environment map of a SCNScene

Tags: ios, scenekit, metal

I want to set a `MTLTexture` object as the environment map of a scene, as it seems to be possible according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents#discussion). I can set the environment map to be a `UIImage` with the following code:

```
let roomImage = UIImage(named: "room")
scene.lightingEnvironment.contents = roomImage
```

This works and I see the reflection of the image on my metallic objects. I tried converting the image to a `MTLTexture` and setting it as the environment map with the following code:

```
let roomImage = UIImage(named: "room")
let loader = MTKTextureLoader(device: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!)
let envMap = try? loader.newTexture(cgImage: (roomImage?.cgImage)!, options: nil)
scene.lightingEnvironment.contents = envMap
```

However this does not work and I end up with a blank environment map with no reflection on my objects.

Also, instead of setting the `options` as `nil`, I tried setting the `MTKTextureLoader.Option.textureUsage` key with [every possible value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltextureusage#1604533) it can get, but that didn't work either.

You can have a look at the example project in [this](https://github.com/svtek/ARKitEnvironmentMapper) repo and use it to reproduce this use case.